# How to convert ONS API Java example to Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, ons-api

I've just downloaded the Java example for the new ONS OpenAPI from http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/apiservice/java and it's configured for WebLogic and gives me errors in Eclipse. How do I change it to use Tomcat and get rid of the errors?

Answer (score 1):

First delete build\weboutput\WEB-INF\weblogic.xml from the project. Then go to the project properties, Java Build Path, Libraries. Remove the Weblogic runtime and replace it with Tomcat. Edit the JRE entry to make it point to the desired JRE on your system.

Finally, there are a couple of errors in explorer.xhtml where it complains that methods on the DataBean are void and do not return a string. Either make them return a dummy string, or go to Window, Preferences, Java, Java Server Faces Tools, Validation, Type Assignment, set Method Expression Signature to "ignore".